# parallax uiviewcontroller stuck when scrolling table on every cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am developing an app that will load remote data from server in a Parallax style UITableView.  and it is loading data perfectly but I couldn't scroll table seamlessly and it stuck on every cell that appear in view when scrolling. Here is my code, the table has only 10 entries in it. Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self hasInternet];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self loadData];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self scrollViewDidScroll:nil];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadData];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
- (void) loadData{
    name = @"name";
    email = @"email";
    thumbnail = @"thumbnail";
    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL.php"]];
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"fname"];
        NSString *title_data2 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"lname"];
        NSString *fulname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", title_data, title_data2];
        NSString *emAil = [dataDict objectForKey:@"email"];
        NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"img"];
        thumbnail_data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/upload/%@",thumbnail_data];
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: fulname, name, emAil, email, thumbnail_data, thumbnail, nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myObject.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"parallaxCell";
    JBParallaxCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableString *text;
    text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:name]];
    NSMutableString *mail;
    mail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:email]];
    NSMutableString *images;
    images = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];
    cell.subtitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mail];
    cell.parallaxImage.image = img;
    return cell;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];    
    for (JBParallaxCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        [cell cellOnTableView:self.tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so very wrong in there `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

Comment: please see my suggestion below :)

Comment: Why not use `SDWebImage` for images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a serious performance issue and I guess this is because this fragment of code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
```

This should be done out of the UI thread! As soon you will download the data in the background and when fetching is completed update UI then your problem with scrolling will vanish.

For lazy loading (downloading) images you have a several libraries on the github ([Nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus) or a category for UIImageView shipped with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library).

I have made a [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/JulianKrl/ios-performance-32912070) that mentions problems like yours.

Simplest solution would be (something like this but still consider using libraries I mentioned to achieve better effect, you can set some placeholder etc):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
         cell.parallaxImage.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    }); 
});
```

Comment: it is working fine but now first and last record keep switching with each other.

Comment: consider using some library for lazy loading images from the web with a possibility of adding placeholders or add them on your own.